# Reactive Backends/ Reactive Server Architectures

Tags: node.js, architecture, server, push, reactive-programming

I've been hearing "Reactive Backends" or "Reactive Servers" on twitter a lot recently. From what I can tell these are Backend Architectures that implement a "Push" architecture. This is really interesting and exciting to hear about and I want to learn more about this topic. Are there any specific technologies (preferably in nodejs) or articles that either implement or explain this type of architecture in detail and give light on how to implement an architecture like this?

Edit:
Please don't post about Firebase and alike or closed source technologies. I want to learn about push/reactive architectures and Open Source Technologies that are working on this so I can contribute to in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a really fast, efficient reactive project with firebase and 
Reactjs. Check out https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/05/using-firebase-with-reactjs.html

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. Don't want a service that provides this. I want to learn about architecture and Open Source Technologies that help achieve this that I can contribute to.